# How can I render an axios response in v-if ? Is there an other way?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

It's my first time with Vue.js and I think I missed some concepts despite reading lots of doc !

I'm trying to display a glyphicon if a call to my api return true.

But it's called in a for loop for each ittération, so I can't store the response into a var as each call will overwrite the previous one...

the code where I want to do the display is here :

```
<div class="list-group-item"
          v-for="item in exercices['data']" :key="item">
          <h3 class="list-group-item-heading titre">
            <p><a > {{ item[1] }}</a>
                <span v-if="checkIsValid(item[0]) === true">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" ></span>
                </span>
            </p>
```

And axios is called here :

```
      checkIsValid(id, index){
        this.$axios
      .get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/checkIsValid/'+id+'/'+ Vue.prototype.$userMail)
      .then(response => ( ??? )
      )
      }
```

Do you have any ideas on how I should do this ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I agree with [@Getan C.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13165683/gaetan-c) but it will depend on where you are getting the `exercices` array from and whether this array mutates after the component has been mounted.

Comment: exercices is the json response from my api, a select * on a table

Comment: I meant to ask the source of the `exercises` array. Where is it coming from in your frontend code.

Comment: Oh ! Sorry !
I have this ```   mounted () {
    this.$axios
      .get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/exercices')
      .then(response => (this.exercices = response))
  }```

Comment: What is `checkIsValid` call for, why don't you send valid responses in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method `checkIsValid` performs an async call, so you cannot use it directly in a `v-if`. I would need to know more about your data object to respond properly but you could check each of your `exercices` elements in the `mounted` hook and store the result in each object.

```js
export default {
    // ...
    data() {
        return {
            exercices: [
                {
                    // ...
                },
                {
                    // ...
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.exercices.forEach(element => {
            this.$axios.get("URL_HERE")
                .then(() => {
                    this.$set(element, "isValid", true);
                })
                .catch(() => {
                    this.$set(element, "isValid", false);
                })
        });
    }
}
```

Note that `this.$set` is required. See more about change detection caveats [here](https://it.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats).

Then change your `v-if` to:

```html
<span v-if="item.isValid">
```